# Usе of разве in questions

Tags: словоупотребление, idioms

In this passage, is this actually a question, or is it more rhetorical, like saying  "Who says that?"

“«Человек в небе»! Что это такое? Разве так говорят? Даже дети знают, что надо говорить: «Человек за бортом!» ”

Comment: this is nice joke actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a rhetorical question. Slightly different connotations than "who says that", it's more didactic and less mocking.

Comment: thank you! So what would be your best translation in the above?

Comment: It would be easier if I had a bigger chink of text to understand the context better, but I would probably translate it something like this: 

"Man in the sky!" What is that? That's not what one says! Even children know that one should say "Man overboard!"

Answer (score 0):

> Разве? in question almost means do?

'Разве' так говорят = 'Разве кто-то' так говорит - Do some one ...?